# Random SerializationException when calling Reliable Actor before Actor activated

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We are getting random Serialization Exceptions when calling a Reliable Actor service like this:

Type: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
Message: Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/:anyType' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'urn:ServiceFabric.Communication:ServiceResponseMessageHeaders'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add the type corresponding to 'ServiceResponseMessageHeaders' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to the serializer.
ToString: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/:anyType' contains data from a type that maps to the name

After research, many say this is remoting library v1, v2 mismatch problem. However, we have the v2 remoting assembly attribute defined in all actor.interface assemblies.

[assembly: FabricTransportActorRemotingProvider(RemotingListenerVersion = RemotingListenerVersion.V2, RemotingClientVersion = RemotingClientVersion.V2)]

Also the exception doesn't happen 100% of the time; it happens completely randomly. Usually in a pattern like this:

1. Failed to call actor service. Throw serialization exception.
2. After a few retries, we see an "Actor activated" message.
3. Calling the actor works now.

It seems happen before the actor is activated. Why does it happen like that?

Comment: Please take a look at the namespaces of the code calling the actor. There might same v1 namespaces used there.

Comment: Thanks, we are using ActorProxy to create an actor reference. Where is v1 namespace you are talking about?

Comment: Well, to connect to a v2 actor you need the `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Remoting.V2.FabricTransport.Client` namespace. See [this code](https://github.com/Expecho/ServiceFabric-Remoting-CustomHeaders/blob/master/src/DemoService/DemoService.cs) in a repo of mine calling a V2 actor. By the way, you do not need those attributes to use v2 remoting on new code as you can see in the referenced repo as well.